# How to fix this type mismatch error? (TypeScript)

Tags: typescript

In my code, `configFields` is an array of objects which have a lot of properties (including `id`, `label` and more).

```
const payloadForm = {};

for (const el in form) {
  const index = this.fields.findIndex((e: any) => el === e.id);
  const fKey = this.fields[index].label;
  const fValue = form[el];
  payloadForm[fKey] = fValue;
}
```

For the `payloadForm[fKey]` bit I'm getting the following TypeScript error:

```
TS7053: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'any' can't be used to index type '{}'.
```

I have no idea how to satisfy TS here. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const payloadForm = {};
```

This infers `payloadForm` with a type of `{}`, an empty object.

You need to give a type that allows it to have the properties set that you need. Something like:

```
const payloadForm: Record<string, string> = {}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.7.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBADgQwJ4BsQICYDEQCcC2AXDAEoCmouGAPNLgJZgDmANDHY0wHwwC8MAbwC+AbgBQYgGZ4YAClCRYZFDEYxpBAJSCxMGAuiqwGMgA8+MKAAt6EAHQLJ9JlnrKM9p8YCSxs7NkyYgQwJG1eHmU+Xn4yO3oMTXE9A1gNfABpMiQLa1sHcCcXNxQPAG1GE1MAXTsUBAAjZWT9cEN0gDUEFABXMgt0suVqlsRUdGw8fDL0rKRqgamu3rJxISA) Which has a lot of errors since the example is very incomplete, but at least it doesn't have the error that you asked about in your question.